# didHighlightItemAtIndexPath not working as expected

Tags: swift, tvos, apple-tv

In regards to a `UICollectionViewDelegate` I'm using `didHighlightItemAtIndexPath` as well as `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`

`didSelectItemAtIndexPath` is working as expected. That is, when I click the remote, this code runs.

The issue is that `didHighlightItemAtIndexPath` is running on click as well, when the name suggests this block will only run on highlight. Am I missing something?

The respective blocks:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let node: XMLIndexer = self.xml!["ArrayOfVideo"]["Video"][indexPath.row]

    let title = (node["Title"].element?.text)!
    let date = (node["Date"].element?.text)!(node["SpeakerOrganization"].element?.text)!

    self._title.text = title
    self._date.text = date
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let node: XMLIndexer = self.xml!["ArrayOfVideo"]["Video"][indexPath.row]

    let videoUrl = (node["VideoURL"].element?.text)!

    self.playVideoByUrlString(videoUrl)
}
```

**Extra Notes**

For the `UICollectionViewCell` I'm getting the parallax feel on the cell's image by adding the following:

```
// self is a UICollectionViewCell
// self.imageView is a UIImageView

self.imageView.adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused = true
self.imageView.clipsToBounds = false
```

## Solution

Override `shouldUpdateFocusInContext` in your `UICollectionView`'s *delegate*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method `didHighlightItemAtIndexPath` called before `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` because of `UICollectionView` arrangement. Every time you touch cell it highlighted before you select it (for visual purpose I assume). You can see it with this example:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("highlight")
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("select")
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: cell.frame.size))
    imageView.image = imageFromColor(UIColor.redColor(), size: cell.frame.size)
    imageView.highlightedImage = imageFromColor(UIColor.blueColor(), size: cell.frame.size)
    cell.addSubview(imageView)
    return cell
}

func imageFromColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
    color.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

When I touch cell output is

```
highlight 
select
```

If you want your cell be highlighted or selected only take a look at `UICollectionViewDelegate's` methods `shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPath`, `shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath`. You can prevent selecting of highlighted cell by checking it's `indexPath` inside `shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath`.

Comment: It turns out what I was looking for was `shouldUpdateFocusInContext`. I said "highlight" in my question when what I need to say was "focus". Regardless, your answer put me on the path to resolving the issue. +1 for a thorough reply.